# NameValueCollection from Form.Post show FIELDS and VALUES

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I need to grab all the FIELD and VALUES from a POST.

I have the follow which only return the FIELDs but no Values.

```
NameValueCollection authForm = Request.Form;
String[] a = authForm.AllKeys;

for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    frm += ("Form: " + a[i] + " : " + "<br>");
}

Response.Write(frm);
```

What can I add this the frm string to show the VALUES ?

**UPDATE:**

I used the initial code of

```
    NameValueCollection authForm = Request.Form;
    foreach (string key in authForm.AllKeys)
    {
        frm += ("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + authForm[key] + "<br/>");
    }
```

which worked great. I will try the new variation below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NameValueCollection authForm = Request.Form;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string key in authForm.AllKeys)
{
    sb.AppendFormat(
        "Key: {0}, Value: {1}<br/>", 
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(key), 
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(authForm[key])
    );
}
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: +1, but it would be prettier if you used `string.Format` or a `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` :-)